# screen zooms randomly on iMac

Tags: imac, zoom

2012 iMac running el capitan 10.11.6

screen zooms in and out randomly. does it with video and maps most often.

Comment: We have nothing to go on... Type 'zoom' in System prefs & see what you have set in Mouse &/or Accessibility

Comment: Many thanks. Didn't know I had a zoom feature with the mouse. Turned it off.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you enabled trackpad smart zoom in System Preferences

- Got to system Preferences **Apple Icon > System Preferences > Trackpad**
- Click **Scroll & Zoom** tab
- Check the zoom options and uncheck Smart Zoom

[image]